# The time complexity of finding the kth smallest number using buckets

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

I've implemented kth smallest number using buckets representing the `current` nibble value of each element in the array where `current` is a value starting possibly at 64 (for 64 bits integers at most) and decrements each iteration by 4 (nibble size).

I was wondering what is the time complexity (worst) of this implementation. I think it's `O(n^log64/4)` which is `O(n^16)`, is that correct?

```js
function nthSmallest(array, k, sizeOfInt) {
    let buckets = [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
    ];
    // put numbers in buckets - O(n)
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const high = (array[i] >> sizeOfInt - 4) & 0xF; // 4 = nibble size
        buckets[high].push(array[i]);
    }
    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buckets.length && numbers.length < k; i++) {
        if (numbers.length === k - 1 && buckets[i].length === 1) {
            return buckets[i][0];
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < buckets[i].length; j++) {
            numbers.push(buckets[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return nthSmallest(numbers, k, sizeOfInt - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is a variant of the [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Consider $k=n$ and the greatest two numbers differ by only the least 4 significant bits, then the two greatest numbers will be always in the last buckets in each iteration except the last. This means you have to iterate for `sizeOfInt`, `sizeOfInt - 4`, ... until `4`, so the overall complexity is $O(nw)$ where $w$ is `sizeOfInt`.

Comment: Shouldn't it atleast be `O(nw/4)`?
Also how do it compares to other solutions for the problem like max-heap or using partial quicksort? Should I consider using this over partial quicksort for example since it's `O(n^2)` worst case?

Comment: @Jorayen $O(nw/4)=O(nw)$. You may want [a more smart solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68125/finding-kth-smallest-element-from-a-given-sequence-only-with-ok-memory-on-t).